# Can I use perl's switches with /bin/env in the shebang line?

Tags: perl, command-line, scripting, system

I want to run `perl -w` using `env`. That works fine on the *command line*:

```
$ /bin/env perl -we 'print "Hello, world!\n"'
Hello, world!
```

But it doesn't work on the shebang line in a script:

```
#!/bin/env perl -w
print "Hello, world!\n";
```

Here is the error:

```
/bin/env: perl -w: No such file or directory
```

Apparently `env` doesn't understand the `-w` flag that I'm passing to `perl`. What's wrong?

Comment: Also see how to do it with a little shell hackery [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9051635/128583) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3306658/128583).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The hash-bang isn't a normal shell command-line, the parsing and white-space handling is different - that's what you've hit. See:

- http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/
- http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/std/hashexclam-1.html#ss1.3
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Basically many/most unixes put all of the remaining text after the first space into a single argument.

So:

```
#!/bin/env perl -w
```

is the equivalent of:

```
/bin/env "perl -w"
```

so you need to handle any options to the perl interpreter in some other fashion. i.e.

```
use warnings;
```

(as @[Telemachus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570183/-bin-env-perl-w/570192#570192))

Answer (score 16):

Instead of `-w` use the warnings pragma (for modern versions of Perl):

```
#!/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about "use warnings", but I'm used to just write "perl -w" and I'm confused that "env" would work on the command line, but not in the script.

Comment: "perl -w" works on Unix, and is more concise, but it doesn't work on Windows (unless ActivePerl or what have you explicitly looks for command-line flags in a shebang line), so it's better to just "use warnings;".

Answer (score 6):

I thought it might be useful to bring up that "-w" is not the same as "use warnings".  -w will apply to all packages that you use, "use warnings" will only apply lexically.  You typically do not want to use or rely upon "-w"

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that Mac OS X interprets characters after the shebang as arguments, so on OS X, the following will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -wT
enter code here
```

However, since one of the points of using #!/usr/bin/env is to foster cross-platform compatibility, it's probably best not to use that syntax even if you're on a Mac mostly.