# Cannot pass an argument to python with "#!/usr/bin/env python"

Tags: python, arguments, shebang

I needed to have a directly executable python script, so i started the file with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. However, I also need unbuffered output, so i tried `#!/usr/bin/env python -u`, but that fails with `python -u: no such file or directory`.

I found out that `#/usr/bin/python -u` works, but I need it to get the `python` in `PATH` to support virtual `env` environments.

What are my options?

Comment: You could have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881696/unbuffered-stdout-in-python-as-in-python-u-from-within-the-program) for a bit of info about how to do unbuffered output.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is better to use environment variable to enable this. See python doc : http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

for your case:

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
script.py
```

Comment: Do you need to do this on every restart?

Comment: @dan: Not while you keep in same shell. After `export` a variable it will keep set until you overwrite or `unset` it

Answer (score 45):

In some environment, env doesn't split arguments.
So your env is looking for `python -u` in your path.
We can use sh to work around.
Replace your shebang with the following code lines and everything will be fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
''''exec python -u -- "$0" ${1+"$@"} # '''
# vi: syntax=python
```

p.s. we need not worry about the path to sh, right?

Comment: For those wondering how this works: [Why does this snippet work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17458528)

Comment: the [`${1+"$@"}` hack](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/sh_dollar_at) has probably been unnecessary for at least 20 years :)

Comment: The hack is unnecessary perhaps, but it doesn't do any harm does it? It's fun to know about it :-) I just learned about it today.  Anyway, I think `"exec" "python" "-u" "--" "$0" "$@"` might be easier to understand - is there any flaw in it?  (I think it's not compatible with the `1+` hack?)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Since the hack is unnecessary, your version works fine and is really much more readable! Great!

Comment: There is a disadvantage with my method. If you want to pass something complicated to bash, such as a string with nested `'` or `"`, then your method is more reliable. It's an interesting issue! Mine is easier to understand perhaps, but yours is more robust. Perhaps your answer should clarify that it must start with `''''exec`, and the string must end in `# '''` (with a space before the `#`). As long as we follow those rules, and don't have any extra triple-quotes `'''`, your method is perfect and flexible.

Comment: Unfortunately this way conflicts with module's docstring. Is there any way to separate that hack and module's docstring?

Comment: @user4815162342 [Here](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/) is more context on `${1+"$@"}`. So `"$@"` should work fine on its own in most cases.

Comment: So in summary, this trick is using python's module doc string to run a mini shell script first.

Answer (score 38):

This might be a little bit outdated but env(1) manual tells one can use '-S' for that case

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S python -u
```

It seems to work pretty good on FreeBSD.

Comment: wow, it would be good if this worked widely, but also not available on cygwin :(

Comment: Seems like the `-S` option is specific to BSD variant of `env(1)` but it's good to know

Comment: Linux has `env -S` now, too - as of coreutils 8.30 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979955/178750) (which may take a while to appear on a distro near you).  Same semantics as FreeBSD's `env(1)` - hooray for portability of good features.

Comment: No luck on Solaris (11.3) either... :(

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env -S node --inspect     -   WORKS!

Answer (score 16):

When you use shebang on Linux, the entire rest of the line after the interpreter name is interpreted as a single argument. The `python -u` gets passed to `env` as if you'd typed: `/usr/bin/env 'python -u'`. The `/usr/bin/env` searches for a binary called `python -u`, which there isn't one.

Answer (score 12):

Passing arguments to the shebang line is not standard and in as you have experimented do not work in combination with env in Linux. The solution with bash is to use the builtin command "set" to set the required options. I think you can do the same to set unbuffered output of stdin with a python command.

my2c

Answer (score 8):

Here is a script alternative to `/usr/bin/env`, that permits passing of arguments on the hash-bang line, based on `/bin/bash` and with the restriction that spaces are disallowed in the executable path.  I call it "envns" (env No Spaces):

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS=( $1 )  # separate $1 into multiple space-delimited arguments.
shift # consume $1

PROG=`which ${ARGS[0]}`
unset ARGS[0] # discard executable name

ARGS+=( "$@" ) # remainder of arguments preserved "as-is".
exec $PROG "${ARGS[@]}"
```

Assuming this script is located at /usr/local/bin/envns, here's your shebang line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/envns python -u
```

Tested on Ubuntu 13.10 and cygwin x64.

Comment: This should be bundled :)

Comment: Note: Most unix-ish #! implementations do not allow scripts to be used for security reasons.  I'm surprised this worked on Ubunut 13.10.

Comment: also works on ubuntu 16.04 as of 2019-01-20, not sure about others.

Answer (score 4):

This is a kludge and requires bash, but it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

python -u <(cat <<"EOF"
# Your script here
print "Hello world"
EOF
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me for another problem ( using the mono csharp shell with arguments )

Answer (score 3):

Building off of Larry Cai's answer, `env` allows you to set a variable directly in the command line. That means that `-u` can be replaced by the equivalent `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` setting before `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env PYTHONUNBUFFERED="YESSSSS" python
```

Works on RHEL 6.5. I am pretty sure that feature of `env` is just about universal.

Comment: FYI, this does NOT work in Debian. I'm not sure why it doesn't work (to look at `ps` output there shouldn't be any difference) but it never returns. It's not very clear if python itself is actually running at all when you do this in Debian. I tried this in a few places - definitely doesn't work as expected versus the equivalent command line.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver. Very likely to do with the version of `env` or even `python` you are using.

Comment: Could be the version of env, but it's not working with any modern Debian variant thus far. It doesn't appear that Python is actually running in this scenario on Debian, making it of limited use outside certain platforms and/or configs.

Answer (score -2):

I recently wrote a patch for the GNU Coreutils version of `env` to address this issue:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2017-05/msg00018.html

If you have this, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env :lang:--foo:bar
```

`env` will split `:lang:foo:--bar` into the fields `lang`, `foo` and `--bar`. It will search `PATH` for the interpreter `lang`, and then invoke it with arguments `--foo`, `bar`, plus the path to the script and that script's arguments.

There is also a feature to pass the name of the script in the middle of the options. Suppose you want to run `lang -f <thecriptname> other-arg`, followed by the remaining arguments. With this patched `env`, it is done like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env :lang:-f:{}:other-arg
```

The leftmost field which is equivalent to `{}` is replaced with the first argument that follows, which, under hash bang invocation, is the script name. That argument is then removed.

Here, `other-arg` could be something processed by `lang` or perhaps something processed by the script.

To understand better, see the numerous `echo` test cases in the patch.

I chose the `:` character because it is an existing separator used in `PATH` on POSIX systems. Since `env` does `PATH` searching, it's vanishingly unlikely to be used for a program whose name contains a colon.  The `{}` marker comes from the `find` utility, which uses it to denote the insertion of a path into the `-exec` command line.

Comment: To anyone reading this and feeling hopeful, the patch [was abandoned](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2017-05/msg00025.html).