# Git: how to deal with different shebang

Tags: git, shebang

How do people deal with different shebangs between local and remote?

For example, my local python is /usr/bin/python, whereas my web host is a purpose-built python at ~/local/bin/python.  A lead developer may have ruby at /usr/bin/ruby, whereas mine is /usr/local/bin/ruby.

I manually edit the shebang, but then git marks it as a change.  Ideally, I would like git to ignore the first line of the file, or perhaps to ignore a regex match of lines within the file.

It seems to me this must be a very common problem, but I cannot find any mention of it.

I use git, but I would not call myself an expert by any stretch.

Comment: Isn't that what `#!/usr/bin/env python` is for?

Comment: @coreyward: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for a discussion of the advantages and drawbacks of the `#!/usr/bin/env` hack.

Answer (score 18):

Change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Then it should work on all your systems, provided you have python and ruby in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The PATH is the issue.  I have a custom-built python in ~/local/bin/python on my web-host.  I can't change the PATH for the web server as I don't have root.  It is kind of annoying to have to change the shebang every time I do a pull or a push.

Comment: [continued...]  I guess my real question was "can git be made atomic at the line level" and the answer is "no, it is atomic at the file level".

Comment: You probably don't need root.  How are you running the script?  Command line?  Via a web page?  Via Cron?

Comment: It's via a web page.  I also have shell access and can run it command line to test it.

Comment: Apache?  PHP?  Ruby?  General answer: call `env PATH=$PATH:/home/user/local/bin scriptname` rather than just `scriptname`.

Comment: @Mikel, but on many systems you can't pass more than a single argument on the shebang line, the whole rest of the line will be passed to env as `$1`.

Comment: You're right.  There's some hacks suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306518/cannot-pass-an-argument-to-python-with-usr-bin-env-python that could work in the general case.  And if running from Apache, two things to try are [SetHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#sethandler) and [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html).

Answer (score 5):

The solution to your problem is git’s smudge/clean filter rule. This allows you to set up filters that will modify files on checkout and undo those changes on checkin. Here’s a nice graphic:

[image]

First set up a the filters that can do the change in both directions, by adding something like the following to you `.git/config`. The smudge filter transforms the file in the repo to the working copy, the clean filter undoes that change. It is important that running smudge -> clean yields exactly the original file. The filters given here will replace the first line with `#!~/local/bin/python` in the working copy if it is `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the repo

```
[filter "pyshebang"]
    smudge = sed '1s?^#!/usr/bin/env python$?#!~/local/bin/python?'
    clean = sed '1s?^#!~/local/bin/python$?#!/usr/bin/env python?'
```

Now activate this filter by adding a line like this to .git/info/attributes (create that file if it doesn’t exist):

```
*.py filter=pyshebang
```

If your python files don’t end in `.py`, just configure the filter on the correct files / a whole folder / all the files. If you set up the filter correctly it will only change files with a python shebang anyways.

I would recommend to read up on [smudge filters](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion), to understand the details of what’s going.

Comment: URL for the smudge filter documentation has changed: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion

Answer (score 0):

This belongs in the comments but I don't have enough reputation yet... You could just remove the hash bang and always run it with `python` when you run it from the command line... maybe...