# How to run Ruby script with env and warnings enabled?

Tags: ruby, warnings

I prefere to invoke Ruby scripts with a hash bang line using `#!/bin/env ruby` which allows me to use a local Ruby installation without conflicting with the systems Ruby installation. But how can I enable warnings on Linux systems? My test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

FOO
```

On Mac I get:

```
maasha@mel:~$ ./test.rb
./test.rb:3: warning: possibly useless use of a constant in void context
./test.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant FOO (NameError)
```

On Linux I get:

```
maasha@orsted:~$ ./test.rb
/usr/bin/env: ruby -w: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have noted the possibility to set `export RUBYOPT=-w`, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: There is a thread on the topic on ruby forum: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/96121

Comment: More on env and multiple arguments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer doesn't work on all systems, so here's another method:  make your first non-comment line

```
$VERBOSE = true
```

which is What the `-w` switch does.  From http://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby:

> -v'
>
> --verbose' Enables verbose mode. Ruby will print its version at the beginning, and set the variable $VERBOSE to true. Some methods print
>   extra messages if this variable is true. If this switch is given, and
>   no other switches are present, Ruby quits after printing its version.
>
> -w' Enables verbose mode without printing version message at the beginning. It sets the $VERBOSE variable to true.

Answer (score 3):

`#!/usr/bin/env RUBYOPT=-w ruby`

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33902713/776723), [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/280937/175529), and other places

Comment: Oh, and now you tell me! After 3 years! ;o)

Comment: Sorry, I just hadn't see your question before - or found an answer, I just went looking again and this time found both

Comment: ... apparently that doesn't work on all systems, so here's another method: make your first non-comment line `$VERBOSE = true`

Comment: You better add that as a separate answer.