# make #!/usr/bin/env python -u shebang portable

Tags: python, shebang

I have this non-portable shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u
```

It is non portable because `python -u` is fed as one single arg to `env` on my system.

Challenge: make this shebang portable **changing the shebang only** - that is to say a **one-liner**.

In other words, no solutions

- from the question [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)
- from the question [Cannot pass an argument to python with "#!/usr/bin/env python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306518/cannot-pass-an-argument-to-python-with-usr-bin-env-python)

Comment: I asked for a solution involving the shebang line only, not a multi-line solution.

Answer (score 11):

I'd use the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
"""true"
exec python -u "$0" "$@"
"""
# python code goes here
```

The line `"""true"` will be parsed by `sh` as `true`, because it consists of an empty `""` string followed by `"true"`. Since `true` is a no-op command, it will be effectively ignored, and the following line will execute the Python interpreter.

On the other hand, Python will parse the `"""true"` line very differently, as the opening of a [triple-quoted string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) which starts with `true"` and is closed two lines below. Since the string is not used for anything, the Python interpreter will effectively ignore the shell snippet that starts up Python. It is the difference in interpretation of `"""xxx"` that allows Python and `sh` code coexist in the same script.

For a simple test, append something like:

```
import sys
print "hello!", sys.argv
```

Given a reasonable `sh` implementation (and taking into account the time to start Python), this should not be measurably slower than using `env`.

Comment: +1 That's dirty, but somehow satisfying

Comment: One drawback is that the hack will be treated as part of (if not the entirety) of the script's docstring.

Comment: @chepner Is this a problem in practice? Docstrings of importable modules are quite useful, but I can't think of a use for docstrings in executable scripts.

Comment: `pydoc` displays the contents of the module docstring as the description of the script.

Comment: Couldn't you continue to add to the end of the docstring?

Comment: There was a similar trick with tcl (playing games with commenting rules)