# how to make a nodejs file executable with --harmony option

Tags: linux, node.js

Generally, I make a nodejs file can execute directly with below style

```
#/usr/bin/env node
nodejs code here
```

But, when node 0.11 support generators, I try below

```
#/usr/bin/env node --harmony
nodejs code here
```

It output

```
/usr/bin/env: "node --harmony": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that, you can however use the path to node directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/node --harmony
```

There're more details on [Cannot pass an argument to python with "#!/usr/bin/env python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306518/cannot-pass-an-argument-to-python-with-usr-bin-env-python)

Comment: I know the OP is asking about Linux but this doesn't work on Mac. Is there an option that will work on both Mac **and** Linux? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshPinter I'm not sure, I've moved on to Go mostly and I don't have access to Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me. Do u miss a '!'?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony

function* genFunc () {
    console.log('step 1')
    yield 1
    console.log('step 2')
    return 3
}

var gen = genFunc();
var ret = gen.next();
console.log(ret.value);
console.log(ret.done);

ret = gen.next();
console.log(ret.value);
console.log(ret.done);
```

Comment: you should do something `function*() {}` and `yield` things to make sure it use `--harmony`