# Automatically invoking pdb/ipdb while using shebang?

Tags: python, debugging

I want to use a shebang line in my scripts, e.g.

```
#! /usr/env/bin python
```

but when debugging I also want pdb/ipdb to be invoked automatically as in:

```
python -m ipdb myscript.py
```

Is there a way to combine these? In other words, is there a version of the shebang that will also automatically invoke pdb/ipdb upon a failure? Something like:

```
#! /usr/env/bin python -m ipdb
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: do you want to invoke the debugger *from the shebang line* or are you wondering if the second line still works even when you have used a shebang line?

Comment: I clarified my question Martijn.

Comment: This is a dupe of [Cannot pass an argument to python with "#!/usr/bin/env python"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3306518) if read one way, easily answered if read another.

Comment: I understand your last comment Martijn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily pass extra arguments on a shebang line, because the shell doesn't parse out the arguments. There are [work-arounds for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051635).

I'd instead invoke the post-mortem debugger on exception, however. If you have a `main()` function in your script, I'd use:

```
try:
    main()
except Exception:
    import ipdb, sys
    ipdb.post_mortem(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

where `ipdb.post_mortem()` must take a traceback object. The `pdb.post_mortem()` version doesn't need it as it picks this up by itself if no traceback was passed in.

Comment: Evidently that does not stop the debugger on the offending line.

Comment: @DaemonMaker: It does exactly what the `pdb` and `ipdb` modules do; catch the exception and take the current traceback as the context for the post-mortem debug session.

Comment: Based on a quick test it does not. Executing a simple test script with an intentional error and your prescribed fix results in:

$ ./test.py
testing
----------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dustin/test.py in <module>()
     10     except Exception:
     11         import ipdb
---> 12         ipdb.pm()

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipdb/__main__.pyc in pm()
    106 
    107 def pm():
--> 108     post_mortem(sys.last_traceback)
    109 
    110 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'last_traceback'

Comment: @DaemonMaker: I replaced `.pm()` with `.post_mortem()` as it uses a better method to pick up the exception. With `def main(): 0 / 0` then the above, the debugger steps into the debugger correctly.

Comment: Okay, so please excuse the formatting of my last comment. That's pretty much useless. The point is tried your solution and it provides a post mortem but does not invoke the debugger for interaction.

I just tried changing .pm() to .post_mortem() and it behaves the same.

Comment: @DaemonMaker: all I can say now is *it works for me*. I tested this with both `pdb` and `ipdb`.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying @Martijn but if it doesn't work for me it doesn't constitute an acceptable answer. ;)

Comment: @DaemonMaker: I tested with [this source](https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/948b91109da46fced225) on Python 3.4 and 2.7. What version of ipdb are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.6. I don't see versioning information for ipdb anywhere.

Comment: Yes, if I use pdb as in the script you link then it works as desired. However that script is not using the technique that you posted in your answer. The difference being that your answer uses ipdb and the script uses pdb.

Comment: @DaemonMaker: clarified some more for `ipdb` specifically. I used 0.8, released in September 2013. You most likely have the same.

Comment: I just noticed that you updated the answer again and that solution (with ipdb) works for me.