# Cannot enable multiple harmony flags nodejs

Tags: node.js, shebang

I wrote a NodeJs script using ES6 features (default parameters and destructuring), so I put the following shebang:

```
#!/bin/node --harmony_destructuring --harmony_default_parameters
```

But then node tells me:

```
/bin/node: bad option: --harmony_destructuring --harmony_default_parameters
```

Both of these options are listed in `node --v8-options | grep "in progress"` so they should be both valid, but maybe my syntax is incorrect.
I tried different syntaxs:

```
/bin/node: bad option: --harmony_destructuring=true --harmony_default_parameters=true
/bin/node: bad option: --harmony_destructuring true --harmony_default_parameters true
```

With no luck.

Comment: Did your question get answered? I believe this is solved in Node v14+ or possibly earlier. This works for me: `#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony-promise-any --harmony-string-replaceall`

Comment: I couldn't find easily a related PR or issue in `node` but it may have been fixed in the last 5 years if it works on your binary. I haven't tried since then.

Answer (score 1):

Although I found [this fascinating answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051635/266795) for python, I don't have something that clever for javascript available. I think you are going to need 2 separate files: 1 small wrapper script to force the arguments you need to node and a separate file for your javascript.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec node --harmony_destructuring=true --harmony_default_parameters=true my-script.js "$@"
```

Comment: Ok that's what I was assuming, shebang has a different parameter handling. Unforunately even with env it doesn't work: `/usr/bin/env: node --harmony_destructuring --harmony_default_parameters: No such file or directory` whereas the same command in my shell works

Comment: That means your PATH does not include `/bin`, which is very unusual. Try `#!/usr/bin/env /bin/node --harmony_destructuring --harmony_default_parameters`

Comment: Indeed my PATH doesn't contain `/bin` (I have archlinux, binaries are in /usr/bin). But your suggestion doesn't work either, I guess env doesnt solve the argument parsing issue and it tries to execute the file `node option1 option2` wich doesnt exist.