# How to get a python script to invoke "python -i" when called normally?

Tags: python, python-interactive

I have a python script that I like to run with `python -i script.py`, which runs the script and then enters interactive mode so that I can play around with the results.

Is it possible to have the script itself invoke this option, such that I can just run `python script.py` and the script will enter interactive mode after running?

Of course, I can simply add the `-i`, or if that is too much effort, I can write a shell script to invoke this.

Comment: Unrequested Public Service Announcement: If you use 'python -i' and like tab-completion, you owe it to yourself to check out [iPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) (Fan, no affiliation.)

Comment: I usually use `import IPython; IPython.embed()` if I want to play around with the state of my application. You might find it useful.

Comment: @Blender why not add that to the answers? Also, OP I think the edit is unnecessary, if a user sees this question, he'll scroll down to see the answers.

Comment: @Jim: It's not that much different from `code.interact(local=locals())`, the interpreter is just prettier. You still have to add code to the end of your script to embed it.

Comment: @Blender fair enough, I'll add it as an addendum to my answer in order to have it in a more visible place.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From within `script.py`, set the [`PYTHONINSPECT`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONINSPECT) environment variable to any nonempty string. Python will recheck this environment variable at the end of the program and enter interactive mode.

```
import os
# This can be placed at top or bottom of the script, unlike code.interact
os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to all the above answers, you can run the script as simply `./script.py` by making the file executable and setting the shebang line, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -i
this = "A really boring program"
```

---

If you want to use this with the `env` command in order to get the system default `python`, then you can try using a shebang like [@donkopotamus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249307/donkopotamus) suggested in the comments

```
#!/usr/bin/env PYTHONINSPECT=1 python
```

The success of this may depend on the version of `env` installed on your platform however.

Comment: This is great! Would you know how to get it working with `#!/usr/bin/env python -i` ? I'm getting a `/usr/bin/env: python -i: No such file or directory`

Comment: @MatthewMoisen There are some platform-specific ways to do it nicely, and also some horrendous hacks that will potentially work in more places. For the full details see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306518/cannot-pass-an-argument-to-python-with-usr-bin-env-python

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env PYTHONINSPECT=1 python`

Comment: @donkopotamus as the comments in the answer I linked mention, that seems to work on some platforms but not on others.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an instance of [`code.InteractiveConsole`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveInterpreter) to get this to work:

```
from code import InteractiveConsole
i = 20
d = 30
InteractiveConsole(locals=locals()).interact()
```

running this with `python script.py` will launch an interactive interpreter as the final statement and make the local names defined visible via `locals=locals()`.

```
>>> i
20
```

Similarly, a convenience function named [`code.interact`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.interact) can be used:

```
from code import interact
i = 20
d = 30
interact(local=locals())
```

This creates the instance for you, with the only caveat that `locals` is named `local` instead.

---

In addition to this, as [@Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender) stated in the comments, you could also embed the `IPython` REPL by using:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

which has the added benefit of not requiring the namespace that has been populated in your script to be passed with `locals`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.interact)?

```py
import code
foo = 'bar'
print foo
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply accompany the script with a shell script that invokes it.

```sh
exec python -i "$(dirname "$0")/script.py"
```