# remove user site directories from sys.path without "-s" in shebang

Tags: python

The `-s` argument to the python interpreter prevents `sys.path` from having user directories:

`-s     Don't add user site directory to sys.path.`

Setting the `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` environment variable is another way to achieve the same result.  Note that setting a user site directory in `PYTHONPATH` and then calling a script with `-s` "overrides" the "user site" removal.

If I do not control how a python script is invoked, is there an easy way to remove user directories in a python script or module?  I could iterate over sys.path and remove any entries that start with `os.environ["HOME"]`.  Is that the right way?  Will I miss any or maybe remove directories that I shouldn't (e.g., what if someone installed python in their home directory, maybe even in ~/.local/... somewhere?)?  Is `HOME` env var the right thing to look for?  I don't see any `sys.path.usersite` that I can use to seed the path scrubbing effort (but see **Update 1**).

Is there a way to scrub user site directories that's easier than adding that iteration blob at the top of all the python scripts?

A shebang line like so achieves this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python -s
```

But if one doesn't want to hard-code the path to the python interpreter, one can use this idiom:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Adding arguments (like `-s`) to the above doesn't work, however, because of the way shebang lines are interpreted on most unix systems (see **Update 2**):

`env: python -s: No such file or directory`

There's two subtle variations to this question:

(1) How to emulate what `-s` does when your script was not invoked with `-s` (including allowing user site directories if they are in `PYTHONPATH`)?  Maybe the best way(?) for this variation is:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec python -s << eof
... python code...
eof
```

**Edit** The above fails if you want to pass args.  This may work better:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec python -s - "$@" << "eof"
... python code...
eof
```

Notice the quoted "eof" to avoid having the shell try to do expansions and substitions in the here document body.

As a side note: that also helps if I want the `python -S` functionality  (which does not have an environment variable knob equivalent) or other python option arguments.

(2) How to emulate `-s` **regardless** of `PYTHONPATH` (i.e., remove user site directories even if they are in PYTHONPATH)?

I guess what I was hoping for was a sys variable that points to the user site dir.  But I couldn't find one.

**Update 1**: Thanks to Blender's comment - the variable is in the site module: `site.USER_SITE`.  So you can iterate over sys.path looking for entries rooted in that directory (could have .egg files in your USER_SITE and to emulate -s, you would need to remove those as well).

**Update 2**: Using `env -S` is another solution.  It allows you to pass arguments to the command spawned by `env(1)` in a shebang line.  FreeBSD has had -S for years (since 6.0).  Linux systems that use coreutils (most) have it as of coreutils 8.30 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979955/178750).  It will take a while for Linux distros to get that version of coreutils, so depending on it for portable scripting is probably not prudent yet (now = 2019).

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S python -s
```

p.s. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3306518/178750) older similar thread.

Comment: What do you define as a user site directory? Python has `site.USER_SITE`, so you could do `sys.path.remove(site.USER_SITE)`.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't find that (I was looking in sys).  Note that you may have to remove more than that (to emulate what -s does).  Example: if you have a .egg in your USER_SITE dir, that is added to sys.path by default.